# Why does this stack trace mean? (LdrInitializeThunk)

Tags: windows, winapi

We're suspecting deadlock in our application and captured all stack traces using Windbg.

I'm seeing ~500 threads with this exact stack trace:

```
ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x14
ntdll!LdrpDrainWorkQueue+0xe5
ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0xa3
ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x89
ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

Is there a way (via Windbg or some other tool) to find out what we're doing that caused the creation of such threads?

Comment: this is thread initialization in win10. thread wait for worked threads finished they jobs

Comment: all threads in user mode begin execute from `LdrInitializeThunk`, then first thread in process call `LdrpInitializeProcess` when all another call `LdrpInitializeThread`. wthis is common for all windows versions. `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` exist only in windows 10 and related to new "Parallel loader". usual this is called when *dll* loaded. but in thread startup/shutdown too. `LdrpDrainWorkQueue` pop and execute work items from `LdrpWorkQueue` or wait when working threads finish work. finally `LIST_ENTRY LdrpWorkQueue` must be *drain*

Comment: What you did was, you called something, explicitly or implicitly, in your DllMain, that caused another dll to be loaded.

Comment: @ChrisBecke - from stack trace clear view that this is *before* thread begin walk through Dlls entry points. and no any dll loaded. this is standard thread initialization code in win 10

Comment: This is the multithreaded loader in action. This thread is waiting for some previous DLL operation to complete so it can start initializing the new thread. I suspect another DLL is stuck in the loader lock.